# AVD Desabilitado no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Não estou conseguindo habilitar o AVD - Android Virtual Device no meu Android Studio, já vi diversos tutoriais, mas não consigo. Se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeco.

Comment: qual plataforma usa? windows linux mac?

Comment: windows 64bits.

Comment: Qual versão do Android Studio? A mais nova?

Comment: Sim estou usando a mais nova versão, baixei hoje... pelo que já consegui entender, tenho que instalar o AVD. mas ainda nao achei como fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Olá, bom dia!

No console aparece um erro em vermelho de dependência de um arquivo, clica nele que resolve. Foi assim comigo.